# Creating multiple records with a single laravel filament form

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I have a form in my Filament resource and for each textarea I would like to create a new record. I can't figure out how to do this.

The form:

```html
return $form
    ->schema([
        Forms\Components\Select::make('quiz_id')
            ->options(Quiz::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
            ->required(),
        Forms\Components\RichEditor::make('steps')
            ->toolbarButtons([
                'bold',
                'bulletList',
                'italic',
                'link',
                'orderedList',
                'redo',
                'undo',
            ]),
        Forms\Components\RichEditor::make('goal')
            ->toolbarButtons([
                'bold',
                'bulletList',
                'italic',
                'link',
                'orderedList',
                'redo',
                'undo',
            ]),
    ]);
```

Upon creation / edit I would like to insert a record for each richEditor:

- id, quiz_id, field_name, value
- id, quiz_id, field_name, value
- id, quiz_id, field_name, value
- ...

I was looking at the function handleRecordCreation in my createRecord class but I can't figure out how to return.

This code manages to store the records as I want but it must return a Model

```html
protected function handleRecordCreation(array $data): FeedbackReport
{
    foreach ($data as $field_name => $value) {
        if ($field_name != 'quiz_id') {
            $record = array(
                'quiz_id' => $data['quiz_id'],
                'field_name' => $field_name,
                'value' => $value,
            );
            static::getModel()::create($record);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Or do I need a totaly different approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are approaching the problem is wrong. I would suggest using a [repeater field](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#repeater).

```php
use Filament\Forms\Components\Repeater;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
 
Repeater::make('members')
    ->schema([
        TextInput::make('name')->required(),
        Select::make('role')
            ->options([
                'member' => 'Member',
                'administrator' => 'Administrator',
                'owner' => 'Owner',
            ])
            ->required(),
    ])
    ->columns(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it

```
protected function handleRecordCreation(array $data): Model
    {
        $userIds = $data["user_id"];
        unset($data["user_id"]);

        $models = [];

        foreach ($userIds as $index => $userId) {
            $data['user_id'] = $userId;
            $model = static::getModel()::create($data);
            $models[] = $model;
        }

        return $models[0];
    }
```

Works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @StealthTrails, I have did your solution but I got this warning
'Return value of handleRecordCreation() is expected to be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array returned'

So I did a little modification:

```php
protected function handleRecordCreation(array $data): Model
{
    //
    $models = [];

    foreach ($userIds as $index => $userId) {
        $models[] = static::getModel()::create($data);
    }

    return $models[0];
}
```